# Как узнать, был ли загружен пользователем файл?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Когда пользователь нажимает на ссылку, что бы загрузить файл, браузер (в зависимости от его настроек) может показать диалоговое окно с вопросом "Что сделать с файлом?" и варианты ответа "Сохранить" и "Отмена". Мне нужно узнать, что пользователь выбрал. Или узнать пошла передача файла или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственный враиант — со стороны сервера, отслеживайте сколько байт было передано. Если слишком мало — вероятно, загрузка была отменена.

Задача отслеживания — нетривиальна. Я бы стал решать в направлении обратного прокси перед основным веб-сервером и самописного модуля, отслеживающего соединения и каким-либо образом рапортующего. Что-то в духе nginx'овского upload progress module, но наоборот, для скачиваний.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Возможно, так можно как-то сделать, но это не настолько важно для проекта, что бы тратить на это время.

Answer (score 0):

Открыть или сохранить - если из этого хотите узнать, что выбрано, то не узнаете. Это для пользователя выбор, а для сайта он в обоих случаях будет загружен. А если сохранить и отмена, то просто давайте скачивать файл через скрипт, например, `имя сайта/download.php?file=имя файла` - это так, грубо если смотреть. Так вы даже можете считать, сколько раз какой файл скачали.

Comment: Не понимаю, как это будет работать. Например, есть ссылка на файл, пользователь жмет на нее, в браузере выскакивает окно. Пользователь делает выбор, если он выбрал скачать, то запустился скрипт, если отмена, то не запустился? Насколько я понимаю, не возможно определить ответ, браузер ничего не отсылает серверу.

Comment: скрипт запускается и начинает отсылку в браузер документа. браузер выдает пользователю табличку скачать или нет. если пользователь выбирает скачивание то документ сохранятеся. в скрипте в свою очередь определяется сколько байт скачал пользователь. если весь файл то все нормально если нет то или порвался коннект или отказ. но в любом случае когда вы видите окно с приглашением "Сохранить", то в это время браузер уже качает. так что даже при отказе файл если не особо большой то уже попадает во временное и будет считаться скачанным что бы вы ни делали на сервере, любые проверки.

Answer (score 0):

Оно или это совсем из другой оперы?

```
<input type="file" onchange="alert(this.value);">
```

Comment: Это когда, пользователь хочет отдать файл, а мне надо, когда он хочет забрать